# excel formula for named range using both offset and count

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a dynamic range using both the count and offset function within count.

Here is the current formula

```
=OFFSET(BATLYearlyPnLListHeader,1,0,COUNT(OFFSET(BATLYearlyPnLListHeader,1,0,0,0), BATLYearlyPnLListRangeEnd))
```

In English, the range is offset 1 down from the header, and encompasses as many used cells as counted from 1 row down from header to the range end cell. But it doesnt work, so I tested using this.

```
Sub Test_YearlyPnLListFormulas()
    Dim rangeCount As Integer

    rangeCount = WorksheetFunction.Count(Range(Range("BATLYearlyPnLListHeader").Offset(1, 0), Range("BATLYearlyPnLListRangeEnd")))
    Debug.Print rangeCount    
End Sub
```

The formula only selects the cell below the header, but when I run the test sub the count is right, 12. What am I missing in the excel formula?

Comment: `=COUNT(header:(end))`

Comment: except i need it header plus one row offset to end

Comment: If the header is not a number then it will not be counted.  COUNT, only counts the number of cells that are numbers.

Comment: @Scott Craner...=OFFSET(BATLYearlyPnLListHeader,1,0,COUNT(BATLYearlyPnLListHeader:(end))) gives a range error, and if I change it to COUNTA it only selects the cell under the header

Comment: `=COUNT(BATLYearlyPnLListHeader:(BATLYearlyPnLListRangeEnd))`

Comment: so we are on the same page, my excel formula is defining a range, the count part is what isnt working and what I was testing with the sub, i need the count withing the offset to define the height of the range

Comment: so the is an XY problem.  What exactly are you wanting to do?

Comment: @Scott Craner...using that count formula within my formula worked, thank you